# How to passing value from main to dialog

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm newbie for using Pyqt5.
I use qtdesigner for building GUI.

I have MainWindow for passing value to dialogwindow

I want to LineEdit( in dialogwindow) show value after user input and click button (in MainWindow)

I try

```
self.ui = Ui_Dialog(self,data)
```

but it doesn't work
My code mainpage
MainWindow.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from dialog import Ui_Dialog

class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def openDialog(self):
        data = self.lineEdit.text()
        self.window = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog(self,data)
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
        # MainWindow.hide()
        self.window.show()

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(505, 236)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 40, 91, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 40, 113, 22))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 110, 93, 28))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.openDialog)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 505, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Passing Value"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Send"))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Dialog code.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(577, 253)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 100, 113, 22))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 100, 55, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Value"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

advice me plz
Thank you,
Mint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyQt recommends not modifying the .py generated by pyuic and Qt Designer but creating another file that uses that class to fill a widget so I recommend regenerating the MainWindow.py and dialog.py files.

Now create a main.py where we inherit the appropriate class by setting a constructor with the requirement:

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from dialog import Ui_Dialog
from MainWindow import Ui_MainWindow

class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self, text, parent=None):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.lineEdit.setText(text)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.openDialog)

    def openDialog(self):
        data = self.lineEdit.text()
        w = Dialog(data)
        w.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: it works!! . Thank you so much bro . You made me know many things for learning.